# Monitor web site visits via my router?

Tags: monitoring, internet

I have a SMC router that my ISP provides for my home cable modem.

Are there any software/hardware products that I can use to monitor what websites are being viewed by the household?

(with the ability to block urls).

We have 2 computers that wirelessly connect to the router.  I want to monitor the other computer that my kids use.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/).

You can block specific sites, block by category, and you can log what addresses are requested.  It will do what you are asking in roughly 15 minutes of reading and setup time.

Comment: +1.  Good answer.  And it'll even log some usage statistics if you want it to...

Comment: As an added bonus, I've found that OpenDNS is slightly speedier than my ISP's DNS servers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the SMC routers, but I know that some of the D-Link Routers allow you to see a listing of websites and you can whitelist certain websites for a specific computer (or all computers) can use.

If you think that it's going to be a major problem, I'd go with the Net Nanny software to restrict usage by categories.

JFV